# Alternating bootstrap grid columns and mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid

I have this design:

Desktop or large screens.

Notes* Red or green boxes are not the same height.

[image]

Mobile or lower screens.

[image]

How to create this layout type on bootstrap 4 grid or custom CSS grid, what is better?

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: You can use order class : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#order It comes with the same responsive variations naming as col classes

Comment: You can use **bootstrap grid** : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks, guys for replacing.
Can you share to me your codepen example? Or something else?

Comment: you should share your code at first , so we can advise you from it. Screenshots do not show much what you've done so far

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, I have this design but i don't have any code (for now). I'm stuck here. I need suggestions.

Comment: @MiloshN: why is there only 1 red box in Mobile or lower screens? Which red box got disappeared?

Comment: okay, Rayees AC gave you a link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/ from where you can get inspired. Looks like you need to learn a bit boostrap :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you would like to build a masonry-like columns, a regular Bootstrap grid system won't give you what you want. Instead, you will have to use the [card columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-columns) or JavaScript masonry plugins.

#### Layout with Card Columns

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="example" class="card-columns">
        <div id="card1" class="card border-success">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Card #1 - height: 20rem;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card2" class="card border-success">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Card #2 - height: 12rem;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card3" class="card border-danger">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Card #3 - height: 18rem;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card4" class="card border-danger">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Card #4 - height: 14rem;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With little bit of styling to setup 1 column for mobile view and 2 for others:

```css
#example.card-columns {
    column-count: 1;
}

@media(min-width: 576px) {
    #example.card-columns {
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

You can get something closed to what you would like to achieve:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/n3fhyp8c/60/

#### Problems on Mobile View

Now there is a problem on the mobile view. Since the order of the CSS columns is top to bottom, left to right, and there is no way to change it, the only way to get what you want on the mobile view is to duplicate contents and hide/show them based on the breakpoints...

Again, your second screenshot is missing a red box so I don't know which one you want to put in the middle. Here I am assuming you want to put both red boxes there:

```html
<div id="card1" />
<div id="card2" class="card border-success d-none d-sm-block">
    ...
</div>
<div id="card3" />
<div id="card4" />      
<div id="card2" class="card border-success d-block d-sm-none">
    ...
</div>
```

Then you can get something you want to achieve on mobile view:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/n3fhyp8c/63/

Comment: you still can use order switching flex for column CSS https://jsfiddle.net/24ydL8nx/ ;)

Comment: Nice! Somehow I thought this has not been implemented by all the browsers or something like that.